# Move data from one column to another in a single transaction/api call

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable

I'm using the [NodeJs library for bigtable](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-bigtable).

I have two columns. ColumnA and ColumnB.

In a single call/transaction I want to move the data from ColumnA to ColumnB, and at the same time delete the data in the ColumnA.

I can do that in 3 steps:

1.. [Get](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigtable/latest/Row.html#get) ColumnA from bigtable

2.. [Update](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigtable/latest/Row.html#save) ColumnB

3.. [Delete](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/bigtable/latest/Row.html#deleteCells) ColumnA

But I was wondering if it's possible to do all these steps in a single call (and ideally single transaction)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn these three API calls into two with a batch mutation, but there is no way to get the value while performing the mutation.

Follow this example to update and delete in the same bulk mutation, but note that the operations are non-atomic

```
const entries = [
  {
    method: 'insert',
    key: 'your#key',
    data: {
      yourQualifier: {
        ColB: ColAValue
      }
    }
  }, {
    method: 'delete',
    key: 'your#key',
    data: [
      'yourQualifier:ColA'
    ]
  }
];

table.mutate(entries, callback);
```

For more information check out the Cloud Bigtable [writing data documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/writing-data) and the [write concept](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/writes) page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's interesting that even though the operations are on the same row, they are non-atomic.

Comment: If you don't need to delete the data in column A but would be fine with it as an empty value, you could update it all in one operation by setting the value to null or an empty string. If you do need it deleted, you could set it to empty and then cleanup the values in a batch job every so often. Just a few options for you to play with

Comment: We ended up using BigtableClient.mutateRow to insert and delete, in the same transaction.